# General scripting best practices when an error occurs

Tags: python-3.x, shell, scripting

So I was in the middle of creating a script that takes in utf-8 characters from stdin and outputs the number of bits the tree takes up + the Huffman tree + Huffman encoding of the characters. I want to use strict encoding so in the event of an unexpected character there will be a UnicodeError outputted to the console (using python 3).

I want to know what is objectively better to do in the event of a crash:

- output to stdout if and only if no error will be encountered.
- Or, output what has already been encoded to stdout with a UnicodeError following it (which gets printed to stderr of course)
- or, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, i think it would depend on whether or not streaming output is useful for your command. Sounds like the output only makes sense if the entire input is validated, so perhaps print any error to `stderr`, otherwise print the result to `stdout`.

Comment: Can you give an example of a problem that would require streaming output?

Comment: like if you're outputting a large amount of data (like converting a file from one format to another) that the consumer will read and process in a loop... here it sounds like you're printing out a small summary of the file so i'm not sure that would apply.

Comment: I see thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help IronMan: Here is a summary.

It depends:

- If you need the entire data file in order to output an answer, it doesn't matter.
- If you can stream the output (like file conversion), then you should error when you encounter it.